# Find Prime number using COBOL

Tags: cobol

I need to find all prime numbers between 1 to 1000 with test cases as :-

1. ENTER DECIMAL NUMBERS-----NEGATIVE TEST CASE

Input = 15.2

Output = Please enter a valid number

2. TEST CASE TO CHECK ALPHABETS, SPECIAL CHARACTER

Input = AAAAA

Output = Please provide numeric values

3. TEST CASE TO CHECK ALPHA NUMERIC.

Input = AAAAA15

Output = Please provide numeric values

4. TEST CASE TO CHECK PRIME NUMBERS.

Input = 13

Output = Not prime

5. TEST CASE TO CHECK NOT A PRIME NUMBER

Input = 25

Output = Prime

6. Can enter integers from -1 to infinity

   a) Can not enter -2

   b) Can enter -1

   c) Can enter zero (0)

   d) Can enter the largest integer computer can handle

With this code I'm able to achieve test cases 4 & 5, however unable to find the solution to other test cases.

```
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
        DATA DIVISION.
        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        77  N                PIC     9(3)  VALUE  ZERO. PROCEDURE DIVISION. MAIN-PARA.
                PERFORM ACCEPT-PARA.
                PERFORM PROCESS-PARA.
                PERFORM DISPLAY-PARA.
                STOP RUN.
        ACCEPT-PARA.
                DISPLAY 'ENTER N VALUE'.
                ACCEPT N.
        PROCESS-PARA.
                MOVE 2 TO I.
               PERFORM UNTIL  I  >= N
                 DIVIDE N BY I GIVING Q REMAINDER REM
                    IF REM = 0 THEN
                        DISPLAY 'GIVEN NUMBER IS NOT PRIME'
                        STOP RUN
                    END-IF
                 ADD 1 TO I
               END-PERFORM.
        DISPLAY-PARA.
                IF N = I THEN
                    DISPLAY 'GIVEN NUMBER IS PRIME'
                END-IF.
```

Comment: Kindly help me with the optimized code which includes all test cases.

Comment: Deleting and reasking the question won't help with anything except getting you question-banned way faster...

Comment: My suggestion to you would be to take one of these cases that you cannot currently solve, attempt to solve it again, and if you have a specific problem with that then ask for help.  But people aren't going to just do your homework for you.

Comment: My formatting to ask the question was incorrect, due to which i tried to put up the question in the correct way, still missed few points like removing db2 and jcl tags. Sorry for making it difficult.

Comment: Ok i will try to execute the code again and will share my inputs if i'm stuck somewhere. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: this should probably go on the code review SE if you are just looking to optimize

Comment: i tried to execute the defined test cases, however code is unable to understand decimal value.

Comment: Err, 13 is prime, and 25 isn't.

Comment: @EJP yes this is correct. But if i enter 23AA then return value should be "IT IS ALPHANUMERIC : PLEASE ENTER NUMERIC VALUE"
Like wise if i enter value 23.23 then return value should be "IT IS NUMERIC-DECIMAL : PLEASE ENTER NUMERIC VALUE", Challenge for me is while defining N with 9(3)v99 i'm able to get decimal values but unable to check alphabet. Because A or X cannot go with V.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. PGM1.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       77  N                PIC     9(3)V99 VALUE  ZERO.
       77  I                  PIC     9(3)   VALUE  ZERO.
       77  REM          PIC     9(3)  VALUE  ZERO.
       77  Q                PIC     9      VALUE  ZERO.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN-PARA.
               PERFORM ACCEPT-PARA.
               PERFORM PROCESS-PARA.
               PERFORM DISPLAY-PARA.
               STOP RUN.
       ACCEPT-PARA.
           DISPLAY " ENTER N VALUE : ".
           ACCEPT N.
           IF N IS ALPHABETIC
           DISPLAY N " IS ALPHABETIC : PLEASE ENTER NUMERIC VALUE  "
           ELSE IF N IS NUMERIC
           DISPLAY N " IS NUMERIC "
           ELSE 
           DISPLAY N " IS ALPHANUMERIC : PLEASE ENTER NUMERIC VALUE " 
           END-IF.
       PROCESS-PARA.
               MOVE 2 TO I.
              PERFORM UNTIL  I  >= N
                DIVIDE N BY I GIVING Q REMAINDER REM
                   IF REM = 0 THEN
                       DISPLAY 'GIVEN NUMBER IS NOT PRIME'
                       STOP RUN
                   END-IF
                ADD 1 TO I
              END-PERFORM.
       DISPLAY-PARA.
               IF N = I THEN
                   DISPLAY 'GIVEN NUMBER IS PRIME'
               END-IF.
    enter code here
```

Comment: This code helps me get the correct prime numbers, challenge is :-
N is defined with value 9(3), and if i use N 9(3)V9(3) still it gives correct ans but then i cannot use alpha numeric.

Comment: How about receiving the input value with X(7) and moving it to a temp variable with 9(3)V9(3). Try it here (http://tpcg.io/0ZB7Eg). I would still recommend you to stick with 9(3)V9(3).

Comment: @SrinivasanJv i tried using this concept but didn't get the results. Infact after using this scenario i'm now unable to even identify prime numbers i.e. numbers which are prime are also coming out to be "GIVEN NUMBER IS NOT PRIME"

Comment: Oh yes! My bad. I just have this question to you. Why would you need to have a decimal input value when the Prime numbers are going to be natural numbers?

Comment: @SrinivasanJv, Well i need to input any number even the alphabet and code should identify the input and return the value acc to the input. Yes it is correct that prime numbers are going to be Natural Numbers. But i want to get results of every possible scenario via code. I always get stuck with the alphabet & alphanumeric part.Tried possibilities which i knew but still failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PRIMENO.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
 01 NUM PIC 9(3).
 01 NUM1 PIC 9(3).
 01 R PIC 9(3).
 01 Q PIC 9(3).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  DISPLAY "ENTER N VALUE".
  ACCEPT NUM.
    
    PERFORM VARYING NUM1 FROM 2 BY 1
        UNTIL NUM1 GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO NUM
        DIVIDE NUM BY NUM1 GIVING Q REMAINDER R
    END-PERFORM.
     IF R=0
        DISPLAY NUM "not PRIME"
     ELSE
        DISPLAY NUM " PRIME"
     END-IF.
STOP RUN.
```

Comment: The upper limit for primality by trial division is the square root of `NUM`, otherwise there are unnecessary tests for a zero remainder. By terminating the loop when `NUM1 GREATER THAN OR **EQUAL** TO NUM`, the remainder from the previous divide will be used for the `IF`. This means that prime numbers show as `NOT PRIME`. The test for `R=0` needs to be inside the `PERFORM` and `R=0` should be used as a terminating condition. Also, keep in mind that `R=0` before reaching the square root of `NUM` means `NOT PRIME`. Please [edit] this answer to provide correct results.